# In eclipse I must use Spark.get() instead of get()

Tags: java, spark-java

In my new Eclipse Dynamic Web Project I have installed Sparkjava with Gradle.

In every  Tutorial for spark i see get() and post(). But when I want to use these same methods i must use Spark.get() and Spark.post() but for the rest everything works fine.

I even imported spark.Spark.*; but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do static imports as opposed to normal imports given that `get` and `post` as static methods of the `Spark` class. So instead of `import spark.Spark.*` you need to do `import static spark.Spark.*`.

Comment: Thank you kind sir!